# How can I JSON stringify the response of a website and save it to a file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

How can I JSON stringify the response of a website and use FS to save the JSON stringified response to a file?

This is my code but it didn't convert to JSON:

```
var request = require("request")
var fs = require('fs');
var url = "http://rubycp.me/"
var http = require('http');


var file = fs.createWriteStream("file.json");
var url = http.get("http://rubycp.me/", function(response) {
    JSON.stringify(response.pipe(file));
});
```

> I simply want to convert the html of the page into JSON and store that
>   into a json file.

Comment: Do you want to convert the web site content TO json or FROM json?

Comment: i used through2 to collect all stream first, then save it after parsing.

Comment: What JSON output would you expect from a HTML document?  One big string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response` is a stream object that does not hold any data. You first need to collect all the data of the stream using the `data` event. If all data is collect the `end` event is triggered, at that even you can stringify your collected data and write it to the file.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const http = require('http')

var url = 'http://rubycp.me/'

var file = fs.createWriteStream('file.json')

http.get(url, response => {
  // list that will hold all received chunks
  var result = []
  response
    .on('data', chunk => result.push(chunk)) // add received chunk to list
    .on('end', () => {
      file.write(JSON.stringify(Buffer.concat(result).toString())) // when all chunks are received concat, stringify and write it to the file
    })
})
```

Comment: This did what I wanted! Thank you so much for you help and effort!

Answer (score -1):

Change it to `JSON.stringify(response.body).pipe(file)`.
I recommend this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var url = http.get("http://rubycp.me/", function(response) {
var dat="";
response.on("data", function(chunk) {
console.log("BODY: " + chunk);
dat+=chunk;});

var x = JSON.stringify(dat);
    fs.writeFile("file.json", x, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
 });
 });
```

Comment: it'll be there coz you cant stringify response. u might be looking to stringify response.body

Comment: I have faced the samr issur and tried to find solutions I read many blogs sites etc. I couldn't be able to find any solution.

Comment: Yes, try to stringify req.body you cant stigify completr req object

Comment: I don't really get how I can add this into my code. Where do I add this? I kinda tried but received ''undefined'' in my file.json

Comment: Nope we can not strigify circular object.

Comment: Stores `undefined` into my json file and why 2x var url?

Comment: sorry my bad check again @JavaSherwood

Comment: Still stores `undefined`

Comment: This will not work if the data is transferred in multiple chunks. You should at least try the code you write, instead of guessing if something you write might work.

Comment: @JavaSherwood it helped?

Comment: This would always write an empty string, because the callback for the `data` event would never be called before the `var x = JSON.stringify(dat);` statement. And the result of `JSON.stringify(response.body)` does not have a `pipe` function.

Comment: on data will end when on end is received from server

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because you are trying to write the `response` object to the file, not the `response.body`, which is where the JSON actually resides. Try this:

```
var request = require("request")
var fs = require('fs');
var url = "http://rubycp.me/"
var http = require('http');


var url = http.get("http://rubycp.me/", function(res) {
    res.on("data", function(chunk) {
        console.log("BODY: " + chunk);

        fs.writeFile("file.json", JSON.stringify(chunk), function(error) {
            if (error) { return console.err(error) }
            console.log('File was saved successfully');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Needs another `});` and stores `undefined` in json file

Comment: That's because the URL you're trying to parse isn't JSON.

Comment: Why would I want to json stringify a json file?

Comment: "How can I JSON stringify the response of a website and use FS to save the JSON stringified response to a file?"

You tell me

Comment: This will not work if the data is transferred in multiple chunk, because it  then would result in either incomplete or corrupted data.

Answer (score -3):

It looks like you are piping to the file before you have 'stringified' the response.

Comment: Just changed in this order:
`JSON.stringify(file);`
`response.pipe(file);`
didn't work

Comment: In that sequence, you're 'stringifying' the file before anything is piped into it.  @Shubham has the right code for you.

Comment: This is not an answer that shows how to solve the problem, its just a comment that tells why it does not work.